# db2 empty string equality comparison

Tags: string, db2, compare, db2-luw

I want to do equal comparison between empty strings('' = '')

Under query not work.
I think ''='' does not work.

```
SELECT RESOURCE_ID  
FROM DEV_RESOURCE
WHERE PHYSICAL_NAME = 'g'                   
    AND 
    CASE WHEN '' = '' THEN '1' ELSE RESOURCE_DIV END = CASE WHEN '' = '' THEN  '1' ELSE '' END
 -- AND DECODE('', '','1', RESOURCE_DIV) = DECODE('','','1','')
WITH UR;
```

Like comment, changing query using decode function seems great but I don't want to.

Comment: '' is null <- this is one answer

Comment: Not sure I understand the reason for `''=''`. Isn't that always true...?

Comment: Do you have Oracle compatibility enabled, by chance?

Comment: @mustaccio Yes I did!

Comment: Well then, since Oracle treats empty strings as null values, DB2 (in the Oracle compatibility mode only) has to mimic this behaviour, and `'' = ''` becomes equivalent to `null = null`, which by definition is never true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is 
"Oracle compatibility".

Before create database I modified registry variable which allow Oracle compatibility. (db2set DB2_COMPATIBILITIY_VECTOR = ORA)

Unlike DB2 Oracle treat null same as empty string('').
So oracle compatibility makes ''='' brings error.